# Possible to make image styles (thumbnails) public while original images are kept private in D7?

Tags: 7, files, media

I love the fact that D7 allows you to choose whether files should be stored in the public or private file system on a per-field basis.

But here's my question: is it possible to have image files that are stored in the *private* file system, while thumbnails etc. created via image styles are stored in the *public* file system, so anyone can access them? In other words, I want to protect the original image files, but not their thumbnails.

By default [theme_image_style](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) seems to place the generated styles in the same file system (public or private) as the original image, and I don't see any arguments to change that...

Comment: I've been wondering this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about creating 2 fields ? One for storing the thumbnail and let it "public". The other one for storing the original image, mark it as "private" and define a permission for it using [field permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module ?

**Edit** Oct, 26: let's add some code :)
So if your confortable with creating a module, here are the instructions.
Create 2 fields: field_img_public and field_img_private, one will be on the public filesystem, the other on the private.

Then create a module to store this [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7):

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  //Retrieve the file object from the public image.
  $fid_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_img_public');
  $fid = $fid_items[0]['fid'];
  $img_public = file_load($fid);

  //Create the private path.
  $img_private_path = str_replace('public://', 'private://', $img_public->uri);
  $private_dir = pathinfo($img_private_path,  PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

  //Verify if the private folder exists.
  file_prepare_directory($private_dir, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);

  //Copy the image
  $img_private = file_copy($img_public, $img_private_path, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

  //Save the resulting file object.
  $node->field_img_private['und'][0] = (array)$img_private;
}
```

Then you just upload the public image and the private get populated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer tostinni, but I'm a little confused... if I used two fields, then I would need to upload the image twice... I don't want to have to upload the thumbnail image, or keep track of it in the database--I want to have the thumbnail created automatically via image styles, as I have it now. I just want that thumbnail image to reside in sites/default/files (public file system), rather than sites/default/files/private (where the original image is, private file system).

Comment: I added some code to achieve this ;)

Comment: Thank you tostinni for the code example! My main issue with your solution is that the original image file is now existing in 2 locations, which is redundant, and eats twice the disc space. Also, it feels very "hacky." But I can't think of a better solution at the moment, so again: thanks for sharing.

Comment: Yep that's the main problem, but I can't see how to achieve this other way...

Answer (score 3):

There is now [Image Style Access](http://drupal.org/project/image_style_access) to do this.

> Allows granular access control to images and image style derivatives.

*EDIT*: Disclosure - this is my module.

Comment: Is this your module?  Normally, we like people to disclose any affiliations when they make recommendations.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm looking for. :) Any chance for a Drupal 8 version?

Answer (score 1):

A possible lightweight solution, which is what I ended up going with, is to save the images in the public file system, and simply use a .htaccess file to protect the original image file directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in a custom module if your are generating images from a custom template.

```
function mymodule_image_style_url($style_name, $uri) {
  $filename = drupal_basename($uri);

  $directory   = 'public://styles/' . $style_name . '/public/';
  $destination = $directory . $filename;


  //TODO: You will need to delete destination folders if you want to refresh styles....
  if (file_exists($destination)) return file_create_url($destination);

  $style = image_style_load($style_name);

  if ($style) {

    $image = image_load($uri);

    flog_it($image, "image");

    foreach ($style['effects'] as $effect) {
        flog_it($effect, "effect");

        image_effect_apply($image, $effect);
    }

    file_prepare_directory($directory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
    image_save($image, $destination);
  }

  return file_create_url($destination);

}
```

Then use it in a node template like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo mymodule_image_style_url('image_preview', $node->field_original_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']) ?>" alt="">
```

Instead of using more modules this solution will boost your website when using your image styles from private file images.